# How to use the values out of sendAsynchronousRequest?

Tags: objective-c, json, sendasynchronousrequest

I am parsing some JSON data using Http POST request and NSURLRequest. But when I have got the values under sendAsynchronousRequest I cannot use those out side of that request. Please see the example bellow:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSError *parseError = nil;
         dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
         NSLog(@"Server Response (we want to see a 200 return code) %@",response);
         NSLog(@"dictionary %@",dictionary);
     }];
```

My query is how can I use the dictionary value where I need it? Thanks

Comment: You could use it **inside**

Comment: @vadian, I want to put those values on a table View. So how can I use it inside.

Comment: Put the code to populate and reload the table view inside the completion block. Think asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. One way is to declare a property and use it inside the block.

As you are making an asynchrounous call, it is better to have your own custom blocks to respond to those calls.

Declare a completion block first:

```
 typedef void (^ ResponseBlock)(BOOL success, id response);
```

and declare a method that uses this block as a param:

```
 - (void)processMyAsynRequestWithCompletion:(ResponseBlock)completion;
```

and include your async call in this method:

```
- (void)processMyAsynRequestWithCompletion:(ResponseBlock)completion{

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSError *parseError = nil;
     dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
     NSLog(@"Server Response (we want to see a 200 return code) %@",response);
     NSLog(@"dictionary %@",dictionary);
     completion(YES,response); //Once the async call is finished, send the response through the completion block
 }];

}
```

You can call this method anywhere you want.

```
 [classInWhichMethodDeclared processMyAsynRequestWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, id response) {
      //you will receive the async call response here once it is finished.
         NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)response;
       //you can also use the property declared here
           _dic = (NSDictionary *)response; //Here dic must be declared strong
 }];
```

Comment: In classInWhichMethodDeclared not getting the dictionary value.

Comment: classInWhichMethodDeclared is where you declared the processMyAsynRequestWithCompletion method.

Comment: Teja, Your code is working perfectly. Thanks. But I want to put my values in a tableView. Not getting the values on the TableView.

Comment: in the processMyAsynRequestWithCompletion, call reloadData for the tableView, and in the datasource methods use the _dic as it contains the downloaded data

Comment: Actually when I call the method on viewDidLoad its getting datas but how can I use those globally?

Comment: You need to use a datamodel that takes this data and pass on to other classes